# How to store and pass CharSequence by setter and getter?

Tags: java, charsequence

I have a `DepositTypes` class with CharSequence array as a parameter. I used setter and getter for `CharSequence depositPeriod[]`. In `generatePeriod()` I have to generate some random numbers and save them to `depositPeriod[]` for each item of the `DepositTypes` class.

In my `MainActitvity` class I need to retrieve `depositPeriod` by
`final CharSequence charSequence[] = deposit_types.get(positionOfDeposit).getDepositPeriod();`. When I check the value of `charSequence` I got  *`[Ljava.lang.CharSequence;@bd8aa05`*

**Question** How to get a CharSequence from `DepositTypes` class and use it in `MainActivity`

```
class DepositTypes {
    ...
    private CharSequence depositPeriod[];

private DepositTypes(..., ...,  CharSequence depositPeriod[]) {
    ...
    setDepositPeriod(depositPeriod);
}
   ... ...

public CharSequence[] getDepositPeriod() {
    return depositPeriod;
}

public void setDepositPeriod(CharSequence[] depositPeriod) {
    this.depositPeriod = depositPeriod;
}

static List<DepositTypes> generateDepositTypes(Context context) {
    ArrayList<DepositTypes> deposits = new ArrayList<>();
     ...
     ...

    Random rand = new Random();


    for (int i = -1; i < deposit_types.length; i++) {
        if (i != -1) {
           CharSequence[] depositPeriod = generatePeriod();     
           deposits.add(new DepositTypes(..., ..., depositPeriod));
        } else {
            ...
            ...
        }
    }
    return deposits;
}
static CharSequence[] generatePeriod() {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int period = rand.nextInt(3) + 3;
    CharSequence[] depositPeriod = new String[period];

    for (int i = 0; i < period; i++) {
        int days = rand.nextInt(335) + 31;
        depositPeriod[i] = String.valueOf(days);
        Log.v("AAA", "in Class -> " + depositPeriod[i]);
    }

    return depositPeriod;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CharSequense is an interface, you need to use the toString() method to access the underlying string value

```
CharSequence[] charSequence = deposit_types.get(positionOfDeposit).getDepositPeriod();
for(sequence CharSequence : charSequence) {
   String string = sequence.toString()
   //... do stuff with string
}
```

Comment: Where should I add use this? Because all data is generating. I cannot get charSequence values by getter

Comment: You wrote in your question that you store the result from calling getDepositPeriod() in an CharSequence array so I figure that is when you need to use toString() to access the content of an array element.

Comment: I edited my answer to have a more complete code example